# The official website of our company is no where to be found on google. How can we put it to the top position among other search results?

Tags: seo, google

We have just built the official website for our company, but it is not listed in the results returned by google even if users input the full name of our company. Instead,the search results are all news reports about our company from other media outlets and very dated.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is not yet indexed by Google. You find that out using the following search operator

```
site:yourwebsite.com
```

To expedite the index process, consider creating an XML sitemap and submit it to Google through the Search Console.